# scroll view for widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm making a widget that contains values from a feed that is pulled from a mysql database. (fortunatley this is not a problem)

My problem is that I need a scrollview within the widget so that the content can be viewed.
Does Anyone know how I can do this? I know I can't have a scrollview in a widget but need an alternative so that content can be scrolled.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

On Android 3.0 and higher, use a `ListView`, `StackView`, etc.

On earlier versions of Android, you cannot scroll, period. All you can do is provide a couple of buttons to rotate the contents of the app widget through your data set.

Comment: on earlier versions, i.e. 2.1 I managed to use a HorizontalScrollView!